# UISegmentedControl show some popup with same options

Tags: ios, iphone

Any idea why standard UISegmentedControl can work like on the screen? 
If try press UISegmentedControl some popup will appear with options from UISegmentedControl...
This popup shows only on some special devices with iOS 10.2 when use touch 3D. If touch 3D off it's not resolve problem, same popup.

It's shows only on single the iPhone 7 plus. Another iPhone 7 Plus work fine, any popups.

[image]

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Looks like some Accessibility option

Comment: Maybe, but I can't detect what is it. I trying change some settings in the iPhone (like touch 3D) but any progress.